# Использование JsonProperty в зависимости от условия

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, serialize, json.net

Добрый вечер.
 Можно ли каким-либо образом в зависимости от флага, пришедшего в хедере запроса
сказать сериализатору чтобы он использовал/или не использовал `JsonProperty` атрибут написанный над моделью?
  Например: есть переменная `flag(true, false)` которую мы получаем из запроса.

```
[JsonProperty("FirstName")]
public Name { get;set; }
```

Если `flag = true`  в `response` мы видим `FirstName`,
иначе в `response` мы видим поле с именем `Name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, возможно, вот пример с [EN SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622492/how-to-ignore-jsonpropertypropertyname-somename-when-serializing-json/20639697#20639697). Придется написать свой ContactResolver унаследованный от [DefaultContractResolver](http://DefaultContractResolver) и использовать его в JsonSerializerSettings для JsonConvert.

```
class LongNameContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        //базовый метод (тут в любом случае будет использован аттрибут JsonProperty)
        IList<JsonProperty> list = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        foreach (JsonProperty prop in list)
        {
            //Берем оригинальное имя поля
            prop.PropertyName = prop.UnderlyingName;
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

---

```
...
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
if (useLongNames)
{
    settings.ContractResolver = new LongNameContractResolver();
}
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ помог с решений проблемы.